# spring batch writer return null prints null in file

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch.
Actually I am trying to validate the data in writer.
So here I got the `Subrogation` (pojo class) from the processor, now I have to check it for validation -- if that object is already present in MAP than don't return that value to File;
else return that data.

So here when I return null in `if`, it prints `null` in the output file.

Actually I want to skip that record from the file to remove duplicates.

Aggregate Method:

```
@Override
public String aggregate(Subrogration subrogration) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    //StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    System.out.println("inside aggregator");
        result.append(subrogration.toString());

        logger.info("Subrogration result" + subrogration.toString());
        if(SubrogrationFileTransferTasklet.map.containsKey(subrogration.getGRP_NBR()+subrogration.getSECT_NBR())){
            System.out.println("douplicate value");
            return null;
        }
        else{
                    return result.toString();
        }

}
```

and the file output is

```
9970150000050
997500150000050
900250000050
99865400001000.0
9980250000100
9986520000100
9999050000100
null
01890001000.0
02076010001000.0
0207640001000.0
02076000001000.0
020760001000.0
02076000001000.0
020703010001000.0
02076880001000.0
```

I don't want that null in my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you should be filtering in your `ItemProcessor`, not the `LineAggregator`.  Your `ItemProcessor` should return null, which won't be written out.  Filtering with the `LineAggregator` is too late in the process.

You can read more about filtering records using an `ItemProcessor` in the documentation (section 6.3.2) here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html